# ShadowRoot property is null despite open

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to access the ShadowRoot on my element and the property `element.shadowRoot` is returning `null`.
The `ShadowDOM` is defined as `mode: 'open'`, which is correct, I can even `console.log(element)` to see all of the properties and `shadowRoot` IS an object of `ShadowRoot` type.

In my app I am trying to access the property like so:

```
let el = document.getElementById('elementId');
...
console.log(el);
console.log("this.shadowRoot = ???");
console.log(el.shadowRoot);
```

Is this okay?

Attached are the `console.log()` output from the console, as you can see the `shadowRoot` definitely is there.
(From the Firefox console)
[image]

I have tried in both latest Firefox and Chrome, both have same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit**

I have created [a little JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnwvoz05/3/).
If you press `F12` and view the console you can see that the element is logged and shows the `shadowRoot` property, but logging the `shadowRoot` displays `null`.

I wonder if this is a bug? Perhaps it is not fully implemented yet?

I have seen [Element.shadowRoot in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028945/element-shadowroot-in-firefox) but I am using the latest (65) of Firefox and (72) Chrome.

Comment: maybe you should provide some code

Comment: I have added a little JSFiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be careful of the script execution order.

In your example you are trying to get the `shadowRoot` propery before the Custom Element is defined.

[It works](https://jsfiddle.net/j3gck0sb/) when you get the value at the right time.

You could use the `whenDefined()` method to be sure the element is defined:

```
customElements.whenDefined('web-component').then(() => {
    let el = document.getElementById('elementId');
    console.log(el.shadowRoot);
} )
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I didn't know about the `whenDefined` method... What about if there are many custom elements of the same name? In my real world app I have multiple `web-component`s - all same tag name

Comment: If there are multiple web components they will be all created before whenDefined is called.

Comment: You could do this for multiple customElements:
```Promise.all([customElements.whenDefined('web-component-1'), customElements.whenDefined('web-component-2')]).then(() => {
  //...
});
```

You can also find other examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined