# How to hide shadowRoot element?

Tags: html, shadow-dom

I'm trying to hide a div (answers-box) nested in a shadowRoot element, but can't seem to do so.

When I inspect the page with dev tools, this is the format:

[image: shadowRoot]

I'm using the following at the end of my code to work with the shadowRoot element:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var crowdElement = document.getElementById('myCrowd');
            console.log(crowdElement);
            var shRoot = crowdElement.shadowRoot;
            console.log('Here is the var: ' + shRoot)
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it comes back as null in the console.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create the shadowRoot?

Comment: The shadowRoot is created by an AWS website that I have no control over.  It gets populated when I create the crowd-form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ShadowRoot property is null despite open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610139/shadowroot-property-is-null-despite-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you execute the `ready` callback the Custom Element `<crown-form>` is not defined yet.

Probably because the loading of the Custom Element definition is deferred or asynchronous.

You should wait for it by using `whenDefined()`.

```
customElements.whenDefined( 'crowd-form' ).then( () => {  
    var crowdElement = document.getElementById('myCrowd');
    console.log(crowdElement);
    var shRoot = crowdElement.shadowRoot;
    console.log('Here is the var: ' + shRoot)
} )
```

Comment: That's super sharp, Supersharp!  I had to change `then` to `.then` but I can successfully begin to manipulate it, now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `crowdElement.shadowRoot` is returning `null` then this Shadow DOM is `closed`. This means that its implementation internals are inaccessible and unchangeable from JavaScript. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode) you can read more about closed shadow DOMs.

Comment: In the dev console (see picture above), the shadow-root appears to be open.  Is this not the case?  In the event that it is closed, how can I obfuscate it away?

FWIW, the div that gets rendered has a small X in the top right corner that closes the div.  If I could find some way to automatically press that button, that would work, too.